# Simple example of d3.js not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graphics

Here is simple html, which will have 2 circle and label on it

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 1<html>
   <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="simple.js"></script>
      <link href="style 2.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body> 
         <h1>Test</h1>
        <div id="small-gr"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

simple.js this is simple example for d3 dashing site .

```js
var circleData = [
  { "cx": 20, "cy": 20, "radius": 20, "color" : "green" },
  { "cx": 70, "cy": 70, "radius": 20, "color" : "purple" }];

//Create the SVG Viewport
var svgContainer = d3.selectAll("body").append("svg")
                                     .attr("width",200)
                                     .attr("height",200);


//Add circles to the svgContainer
 var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                            .data(circleData)
                            .enter()
                            .append("circle");

// //Add the circle attributes
 var circleAttributes = circles
                        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.cx; })
                       .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.cy; })
                        .attr("r", function (d) { return d.radius; })
                       .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; });

//Add the SVG Text Element to the svgContainer
var text = svgContainer.selectAll("text")
                        .data(circleData)
                        .enter()
                        .append("text");

//Add SVG Text Element Attributes
var textLabels = text
                 .attr("x", function(d) { return d.cx; })
                 .attr("y", function(d) { return d.cy; })
                 .text( function (d) { return "( " + d.cx + ", " + d.cy +" )"; })
                 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
                 .attr("font-size", "20px")
                 .attr("fill", "red");
```

Our problem is very weird , if you see the `<html>` tag you can find `1` there , that's what we have to use so that the code works, but if you remove it the code doesn't work , this has no edit it's directly taken from  d3 site. Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Comment: Place your javascript code right before `</body>`